# Domain of definition of a hamiltonian with delta(contact) potential

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I am having a hard time making sense of the so-called "delta function potential well" in quantum theory. The Hamiltonian operator is defined as (with $\mathscr D_H\subset \mathscr H=L^2(\mathbb R)$)
$$H:\mathscr D_H\rightarrow \mathscr H$$
$$\psi\mapsto H\psi$$
And
$$(H\psi)(x):=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)-\lambda\delta(x)\psi(x).$$
My job is to find the spectrum of this operator given a $\lambda>0$.

My problems are:

1. How do I construct $\mathscr D_H$?
2. What definition of the "delta function" is suitable for this kind of job?

Comment: The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential) constructs explicit solutions. The domain would be functions with a kink at the origin like the eigenfunction shown there. Are you interested in showing that $H$ is essentially self-adjoint (in the rigorous meaning for unbounded operators)?

Comment: Yes, that would be what I want to show. Also, is that domain dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: [Here p.150](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3aed/2ba1dc8fc1e8418092da70949a6cddab0e6a.pdf) is one approach (for a finite interval).

Comment: What is your background in functional analysis? Do you have theorems that smooth functions are dense in $L^2$ (for finite intervals, at least)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rigorous formulation

When mathematical physicists work with point interactions, the “delta” in the potential is only a formal shorthand. What they actually mean are the corresponding boundary conditions $$\psi'(0+) - \psi'(0-) = -\lambda \, \psi(0) \: .$$
The Hamiltonian in your question is then rigorously defined as:
\begin{gather*}
\mathscr D_H = \big\{ \;
  \psi \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb R) \cap W^{2,2}(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})
  \;\; \big| \;\;
  \psi'(0+) - \psi'(0-) = -\lambda \, \psi(0)
  \; \big\} \: ,
  \\[10pt]
  \big( H \psi \big)(x) = -\psi''(x)
  \quad \text{ for a.e. } \quad x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \: ,
\end{gather*}
where $W^{k,p}$ are the Sobolev spaces of $k$-times weakly differentiable $L^p$ functions.

### Self-adjointness

You can check that this Hamiltonian is indeed self-adjoint:
\begin{align*}
  ( H\psi, \varphi)
  &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!\! -\overline{\psi''} \, \varphi
  \;=\; \int_{-\infty}^{0} \!\!\! -\overline{\psi''} \, \varphi
  \;+\; \int_{0}^{+\infty} \!\!\! -\overline{\psi''} \, \varphi
  \\[5pt]
  &= \big[-\overline{\psi'}\varphi \big]_{-\infty}^{0}
  + \big[ -\overline{\psi'}\varphi\big]_{0}^{+\infty}
  \;+\; \int_{-\infty}^{0} \!\!\! \overline{\psi'} \, \varphi'
  \;+\; \int_{0}^{+\infty} \!\!\! \overline{\psi'} \, \varphi'
  \\[5pt]
  &= \big[-\overline{\psi'}\varphi \big]_{-\infty}^{0}
  + \big[ -\overline{\psi'}\varphi\big]_{0}^{+\infty}
  + \big[-\overline{\psi}\varphi' \big]_{-\infty}^{0}
  + \big[ -\overline{\psi}\varphi'\big]_{0}^{+\infty}
  + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!\! -\overline\psi \, \varphi''
  \\[5pt]
  &= \big[-\overline{\psi'}\!\varphi -\overline{\psi}\varphi' \big]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - \lambda \, \overline\psi(0) \, \varphi(0) + \overline\psi(0) \, \big( \varphi'(0+) - \varphi'(0-) \big)
  + \!\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!\!\!\! -\overline\psi \, \varphi''
\end{align*}
which is equal to $(\psi, H\varphi)$ exactly iff $\varphi \in \mathscr D_H$. Really, the terms at $\pm\infty$ are zero, because functions from $W^{1,2}$ vanish at infinity ([proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/438009/42966)) and the terms at $0\pm$ exactly cancel out if $\varphi$ obeys the boundary condition.

### Motivation

This might seem unsatisfactory, because the rigorous formulation sidesteps the “multiplication by delta” operator. Therefore I will hint at a construction that follows the formal notation more closely. Choose your favourite space of test functions $\mathcal D$ (eg. smooth functions with compact support) and the space of continuous linear functionals on it $\mathcal D'$. Since $\mathcal D$ is naturally embedded in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is naturally embedded in $\mathcal D'$, we have the famous [Gelfand sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) $\mathcal D \subset \mathcal H \subset \mathcal D'$. Now we can define two operators. The first one is the distributional second derivative:
$$
  \hat \Delta: \mathcal H \to \mathcal D' \: ,
  \qquad
  \langle \hat \Delta \psi, \varphi \rangle = \int \psi \, \varphi''
  \quad \forall \psi \in \mathcal H
  \quad \forall \varphi \in \mathcal D \: .
$$
This is exactly how derivatives work on distributions ([source](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derivative+of+a+distribution)). The second operator we define is the operator of multiplication by delta:
$$
  \hat \delta: \big\{ \; \psi \in \mathcal H \; \big| \; \psi \text{ is continuous at } 0 \; \big\} \to \mathcal D' \: ,
  \;\;
  \langle \hat \delta \psi, \varphi \rangle = \psi(0) \, \varphi(0)
  \;\, \forall \psi \in \mathcal H
  \;\, \forall \varphi \in \mathcal D \: .
$$
Now we can rigorously define the Hamiltonian as $\hat H = -\hat \Delta - \lambda \hat \delta$ which is an operator from a subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to the distributions $\mathcal D'$. We could ask if there is a restriction of $\hat H$ to a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Yes, there is – it is $H = \hat H|_{\mathscr D_H}$, as defined above!